# anytomany field and a foreignkey to the same model class in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I set a manytomany field and a foreignkey to the same model class in a django model.
My data structure is similar to a linking list.

```
class cls_object(models.Model):
    child = models.ManyToManyField('cls_object')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('cls_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

django always tells me to change one of the two:

```
ERRORS:
cls_object: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'cls_object.child' clashes with reverse accessor for 'cls_object.parent '.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'cls_object.child' or 'cls_object.parent'.
cls_object: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'cls_object.parent' clashes with reverse accessor for 'cls_object.child'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'cls_object.parent' or 'cls_object.child'.
```

i would like to have the opportunity to find out its parents from the respective object and have to know which objects emanate from it. A loop would not be possible (syntax, of course, yes). should one possibly do this differently?

The error is sure that he does not know how to resolve it clearly in the database, but something like that should work anyway, right? am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two relations that point to the same model. Thus, the default [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) have the same name, which is ambiguous and now allowed by Django. This is what the error message tells you.

To fix this, you have to use explicit different related names:

```
class cls_object(models.Model):
    child = models.ManyToManyField('cls_object', related_name='parents')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('cls_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children', blank=True, null=True)
```

That being said, `related_name` is actually what allows you to handle [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). This mechanism allows you to reverse a relation without the redundancy of `child`/`parent` that you have in your code. You can just do the following:

```
class cls_object(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('cls_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children', blank=True, null=True)

obj1 = cls_object.objects.create(...)
obj2 = cls_object.objects.create(parent=obj1, ...)
obj3 = cls_object.objects.create(parent=obj1, ...)
obj4 = cls_object.objects.create(parent=obj3, ...)
obj4.parent  # <- obj3
obj3.children.all()  # <- [obj4]
obj1.children.all()  # <- [obj2, obj3]
```